# Angular with Firebase Cloud Messaging - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I trying to post a message to Firebase Cloud Messaging with Angular without success, because I have been received following issue message:

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

I have a very simple post with Angular as the Firebase documentation says: [Send Messages | Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages)

```
sendMessage() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `key=${environment.firebaseConfig.serverKey}`);
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials: true
    });

    const message = { 
      'notification': { 
        'title': 'MESSAGE TEST',
        'body': 'Its works fine',
        'click_action': 'https://www.google.com.br'
      },
      "to": this.token
     }

    this.$http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', JSON.stringify(message), options)
      .subscribe(m => { 
        console.log(m);
      }, error =>  {
        console.log(error);
      })
}
```

I tried a lot of things, but dont works...

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to fix in Angular, because you are trying to `POST` to an other domain. Chrome and other browsers deny these requests (security). So you have to enable CORS headers on the server side. But that's not possible because you are using a Google API.

Here you can read about CORS and Angular:
https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

A solution is to send these notifications in the backend of your application.